# Flutter Google-SignIn via Flutter idToken issues

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am trying to get an idToken from my client Flutter app to send back to my backend for verification, the problem is I either don't get the idToken but rather an "instanceOfGetIDToken" or something along those lines or it spits out a token that does not have anything to do with the Firebase app it's linked to, I'm quite confused since the user appears in the Firebase console for the app but the consent screen mentions the idNumber instead of the name and when I check the JWT it has somewhat okay information but the issuer and everything is different?

```
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
Future<FirebaseUser> _handleSignIn() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );

  final FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
  print(credential);
  return user;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using this?

```
Future<FirebaseUser> _handleSignIn() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken, 
  );

  final FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;

  print(user);
  return user;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply, FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithGoogle() throws an error. Is it a method inside the plugin or?

Comment: .signInWithGoogle stills throws an error for some reason. I can't figure it out, the docs of the plugin might be wrong?

Comment: What firebase package are you using?

Comment: Updated my answer again

Comment: await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential); still throws an error, neither casting as Firebase User nor changing it to AuthResult works. Still throws Instance of 'Future<IdTokenResult>'. I updated Flutter yesterday, what version are You on?

Comment: Whoops put `.user` at the end

Comment: I really appreciate Your help but I'm still stuck. I don't know why it's not working it just keeps throwing the instance of future<idtokenresult> :(  I don't understand it because it gets the email, uid and everything normally

Comment: I figured it out, at first I didn't know why the token had a weird issuer and a different signing pattern, I was probably getting the Google API token or something along those lines. After that I messed around with it and got it to spit out a correct token but not a valid one, turns out the log cuts out after a 1000 characters. Tried it again without copying but directly using verify idToken and it works :D Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want access token

```
AuthCredential authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken, accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the ID token that you get from the Google sign-in process with your Firebase project. I'm not sure that Google sign-in token is a valid ID token for a Firebase project. Instead you'll want to exchange the Google credentials for Firebase credentials (as you already do with `signInWithCredential`) and get the ID token from *that* with:

```
user.getIdToken()
```

Comment: Hi mate! I kinda got lost, do You maybe have the method in which I exchange the credentials? I can't seem to figure it out. Thank You!

Comment: Your existing call to `signInWithCredential` is already exchanging the credentials.After that you can get the **Firebase** ID token from `user.getIdToken()`.

Comment: I tried that but it returns Instance of 'Future<IdTokenResult>'.

Comment: If you get a `Future` you can either attach a `then()` to it, or use `await`. So for example `await user.getIdToken()`.

Comment: I figured it out, at first I didn't know why the token had a weird issuer and a different signing pattern, I was probably getting the Google API token or something along those lines. After that I messed around with it and got it to spit out a correct token but not a valid one, turns out the log cuts out after a 1000 characters. Tried it again without copying but directly using verify idToken and it works :D Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, at first I didn't know why the token had a weird issuer and a different signing pattern, I was probably getting the Google API token or something along those lines. After that I messed around with it and got it to spit out a correct token but not a valid one, turns out the log cuts out after a 1000 characters. Tried it again without copying but directly using verify idToken and it works :D Thanks again!

```
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Future<FirebaseUser> _handleSignIn() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
  idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
  );

  final FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
  IdTokenResult mytoken = await user.getIdToken();
  String token = mytoken.token.toString();
  return user;
  }
```